# Azure mySQL Database disappeared

Tags: mysql, azure, cleardb

I'm using a mySQL DB by ClearDB in Azure.
Now I've reached the limit and get appropriate warning mails by ClearDB.

Now I want to increase the plan, but in Azure the mySQL database is missing. I can't find an entry anywhere.
The ClearDB support says that this would be - maybe - an error of azure and my database is still active at ClearDB.

What can I do?
Must I recreate the database with a higher plan? Or is there really an error in Azure?

Comment: So it's not just me! I had no warnings, no nothing, just had my entire database disappear overnight. I look in the clearDB backups and it has heaps but they're all 1Mb as if nothing was ever saved. WTF?

Comment: My result was: Wordpress is now no longer hosted on Azure. I'm using managed Wordpress on GoDaddy now. I do not recommend ClearDB with Azure. Only the support was fine.

Comment: I opened a support ticket with ClearDB and was told nothing is wrong try again, yet mysteriously the DB appeared again only after they noticed 'nothing' wrong.

Comment: In my case ClearDB said I have to contact Azure Support. Azure Support said this is a Third Party App, I do not have a plan for this request and I should contact the developer, ClearDB. Was quite nice..... ;-)